# how to make global variable from result json table? :SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I don't know how to declare global variable with this struct POST please help me

```
import Foundation

struct Results: Decodable {
    let Table: [Post]
}

struct Post: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        return name
    }
    let name: String
    let cellPhone: String
}

// I want to get value like this but this didn't work
var data1 = name
var data2 = cellPhone
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are asking, but how about this:

```
let results = Results()
let aPost = Post(name: "myname", cellPhone: "123456")
results.table.append(aPost)

for post in results.table {
let data1 = post.name
let data2 = post.cellPhone
print("---> data1: \(data1) data2: \(data2)")
}

class Results: Decodable {
var table = [Post]()
}

struct Post: Decodable, Identifiable {
var id: String { return name }
let name: String
let cellPhone: String
}
```